# How can I know the function used to CAST data types in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

How can I know which function used by `CAST` to convert data type to anothor  in Postgresql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions used to convert data types are referenced in system catalog [pg_cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html): this system catalog is referencing [pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) and [pg_proc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html) system catalogs.

Comment: Thank you. I used this query `select s.typname sourcename, t.typname  targetname,p.proname,pg_cast.* 
from pg_cast left join pg_type s on castsource=s.oid 
left join pg_type t on casttarget=t.oid
left join pg_proc p on castfunc=p.oid 
WHERE s.typname='timestamp' AND s.typname='date'` to determine function casts timestamp as date.